# MySQL - "select" query inside IN (...) optimization issue (=> Hierarquical query )

Tags: mysql, sql-optimization

Before you start down voting and deny me an answer, please note that I am a complete beginner :). I already searched for an answer but it seems to be quite specific.

*(how I understand it as a programmer, if the select statements where for loops, it would be like a loop inside a loop inside a loop :D)*

The question is about Optimizing my sql query because it takes a few seconds to fetch the data.

The SQL Broken down:

**1st.** query

```
SELECT * 
FROM r_submenuitems 
WHERE modifier1 IN (SELECT submenu_id FROM r_submenuitems WHERE item_id = 1068)
```

this query gets a list (the list in the 2nd query to be exact), and I want to go one step higher. I.e. use this list in the IN clause of the query once again and fetch the new list.

**2nd.** query

```
SELECT submenu_id 
FROM r_submenuitems 
WHERE modifier1 IN (31050, 131050,3912, 103122, 103165, 7772, 7782)
```

---

To merge the 2 querys into 1, I did the following:

```
SELECT submenu_id FROM r_submenuitems 
WHERE modifier1 IN (SELECT submenu_id FROM r_submenuitems 
    WHERE modifier1 IN (SELECT submenu_id FROM r_submenuitems 
        WHERE item_id = 1068))
```

Which takes ages to fetch the data.

**Is there a better (quicker to fetch) way** to merge the two querys above than this?? **If not,** is the first solution, ie having 2 querys better than having the all-in-one query??

**edit:** The first query returns a list of entries (31050, 131050,3912, 103122, 103165, 7772, 7782). Which I then proceed to feed into the 2nd query. The all-in-one query attempts to merge this two into one, i.e. go even deeper
Check comments of approved answer, turns out what I was looking for is called Hierarquical query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT submenu_id  
  FROM r_submenuitems r1
           INNER JOIN r_submenuitems r2
             ON r1.modifier1 = r2.submenu_id
 WHERE r2.item_id = 1068
```

Your query is fetching your table three times and that is why it is taking so long. And one of then is completelly unnecessary, you are just repeating the code.

```
SELECT submenu_id FROM r_submenuitems 
 WHERE modifier1 IN (SELECT submenu_id                   --All this IN statement is
                       FROM r_submenuitems               --unnecessary you are already
                      WHERE modifier1 IN ( SELECT submenu_id -- doing on the inner IN
                                             FROM r_submenuitems 
                                            WHERE item_id = 1068
                                         )
                    )
```

**Edit 2**

As discussed on the comments you are looking for a **Hierarquical Query**, since mysql doesn't support this kind of operation on native commands you have at least to know how deep you want to go to create a query to fetch the data from that level, you will see that it needs to add a `JOIN` operation for every level.

The alternative to that is to create a store procedure with some recursion (I will not explain this) take a look here [MANAGING HIERARCHICAL DATA IN MYSQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

The query for your problem would be (for the third level)

```
SELECT r1.submenu_id  
  FROM r_submenuitems r1 
        INNER JOIN r_submenuitems r2 ON r1.modifier1 = r2.submenu_id
        INNER JOIN r_submenuitems r3 ON r2.modifier1 = r3.submenu_id
 WHERE r3.item_id = 1068
```

Comment: indeed I am BUT, the data it fetches are different, your suggestion brings the first list, so its the same as my first query. I guess its the way the data are stored. It has a parent which has a grand-parent which has a grand-grand-parent, and I want the grand-grand-parent list :D

Comment: There is no difference from the first and the second query. Only that the second you are fetching only one field `submenu_id` which can be added easelly on my query. Unless you mix the names of the tables on your question is all the same.

Comment: hmm maybe I wasnt clear in my question, Ill edit it and you let me know it it is any clearer :)

Comment: Now I understand. You are looking for a Hierarquical query. Edit your question to be clear on this point, also add sample data of your table just with the columns that matter and your desired result.

Comment: hm its really hard to write it because there is no table thingy =[ it might take a while or if you prefer i could add a screenshot

Comment: thank you it is perfect :). Ill edit my title to include Hierarquical query

Comment: Glad that I could help.